# eclipse--checked out previous commit to look around, now want to go back

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using the latest Eclipse + eGit.

I needed to go back and look around at my previous commit so I went to the History tab and right clicked on the previous commit and selected "Checkout".

Now I'd like to go back to the commit I was on before I checked out the old one--but in the History view that commit isnt' there.

```
58504cb  Added feature z 
09a2df3  Added feature y, Checked out this commit
988c14b  Added feature x
5a76bef  Added feature w
```

When I checked out that commit, the history view looks like this now:

```
09a2df3  Added feature y 
988c14b  Added feature x
5a76bef  Added feature w
```

The problem is I don't know the hash for the "Added feature z" commit.  How can I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the history view, there's a toolbar icon for "Show All Branches and Tags". In [this screenshot](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Inspect_History) it's the cyan one on the right-hand side with the arrow branching into two.

If you turn this on, your newest commit should reappear.